# Install Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10

I have Ubuntu 12.10 Studio and I want to install normall 12.10 from memory stick, but the boot menu doesn't show up as it did on Windows 7... grub doesn't show it as well

Comment: If your USB disk doesn't show the grub menu although you've booted your PC properly from USB (this procedure has nothing to do with Windows or any other OS installed in your PC), it is probably because your live USB disk is not in good shape. Perhaps you need to test it on another machine and/or re-create a live USB disk.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following below in order, and I think we'll be fine...

- Install ISO to USB, which can be found [here](http://www.isotousb.com/).
- Execute ISO to USB on Windows 7
- Direct the application at your ISO file
- Select the drive where your USB is located
- Choose your file system
- Assign a label to your volume
- **Do Not** check "Bootible". This only supports Windows ISOs
- Check you've done all the steps above, then click "burn" when you're ready.

Now write these next steps down, you *will* need these.

- Shut down your computer
- When starting up your computer, press the hotkey for the BIOS menu (usually F8 or F12)
- In your menu, press "boot options" or something along that line.
- On your boot list, move the USB drive to the top, notably above the hard drive.
- Escape and save all your actions

By now, you should booting off of your USB. Now complete regular installation procedures.